# else header not open in login function

Tags: php, jquery, sql, phpmyadmin

else header not work in login function

```
if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){    
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result));  {

    if(!empty($row)) {

        header('Location:welcome.html');
    }
    else {
        header('Location:password_wrong.html');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `;` after the `while` statement a typo?

Comment: and the while loop doesn't close

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)); {
```

to

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
```

no

```
;
```

Comment: What will happen if OP said the `;` is just a typo?

Comment: @Swellar You make a good point - this is just one of many errors. A quick glance shows that OP also has mis-matched curly brackets at the end of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `exit();` after each `header('Location:...);`

The header()-function doesn't stop the script by itself, so the script below the if/else will still get executed. The exit()-function makes sure that the scripts stops after the header()-function.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the computer understands your code:

```
if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){    
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    }

    {
        if(!empty($row)) {
            header('Location:welcome.html');
        } else {
            header('Location:password_wrong.html');
        }
    }
```

1. There is a missing closing brace at the end (or somewhere else - the position is very important)
2. Fixing the indentation often help understanding such problems
3. The empty() after the while loop works AFAIK, but it's very unusual. Rethink your code and verify it's really what you wanted.

   - if the while loop line doesn't have a closing brace and no semicolon, the if condition goes inside the loop. If this is what you wanted: the `empty()` function will always return false (= `!empty()` is always true)
4. I assume your query returns rows if the login was successful, and nothing if the login failed.